# How do I stop text_file overriding previously written lines?

Tags: python, overriding, text-files

I've got my code, I'm trying to make a mood diary of some sorts, **it works fine**, but when I go back to the script and run it again to add another entry, **it just overrides my last entry**, how could i prevent this?

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.now()
print('My Mood Diary:')
mood = input('How are you feeling today? ')
text_file = open("Diary.txt", "w")
text_file.write('Date:\n')
text_file.write(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d @ %H:%M:%S\nEntry:\n"))
text_file.write(mood)
text_file.write('\n')
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Open it in append mode: `text_file = open("Diary.txt", "a")`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python

Comment: I think the title of the duplicate question definitely is not beginner friendly. Could it be made better?

Answer (score 0):

Use `append`:

```
text_file = open("Diary.txt", "a")
                               ^
```

Comment: thanks :) i had forgotten i could change the modes